# PHP global array is disappearing

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is the menu generator for my website.

```
<?php

$mx_grid = null;
$mx_generated_menu = '';
$mx_menu_colors = [
    'blue',
    'red',
    'blue',
    'green',
    'purple',
    ''
];

define('MENU_PAGE', 0);
define('MENU_ACTION', 1);
define('MENU_USER', 2);
define('MENU_LOCAL', 3);
define('MENU_ADMIN', 4);

for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++) {
    $mx_grid[$i] = [];
    for ($j = 0; $j < 6; $j++)
        $mx_grid[$i][$j] = ['null', 6];
}

print_r($mx_grid);

function _menu_add_cell($x, $y, $action, $type) {
    global $mx_grid;
    $arr = array($action, $type);
    $mx_grid[$y][$x] = $arr;
}

function _menu_compile() {
    global $mx_grid;
    global $mx_generated_menu;
    global $mx_menu_colors;
    $mx_menu_rows = 32;
    $mx_menu_cols = 6;

    print_r($mx_grid);

    $s_t = '';
    $s_r = '';
    $s_i = '';
    $s_c = '';
    for ($r = 0; $r < $mx_menu_rows; $r++) {
        $mx_row = $mx_grid[$r];
        $s_r = "\t<div class='mx_grid mx_menu_grid'>\n";
        for ($c = 0; $c < $mx_menu_cols; $c++) {
            $mx_cell = $mx_row[$c];
            $s_c = $mx_menu_colors[$mx_cell[1]];
            $s_i = "\t\t<div class='mx_grid_cell mx_menu_btn $s_c' href='$mx_cell[0]'></div>\n";
            $s_r .= $s_i;
        }
        $s_r .= "\t</div>\n";
        $s_t .= $s_r;
    }
    $mx_generated_menu = $s_t;
}

_menu_add_cell(1, 1, '/api/meh', MENU_PAGE);

print_r($mx_grid);

_menu_compile();

print_r($mx_grid);
```

The problem is, somewhere between the initialization loop and the `_menu_compile()` call, the array goes south.

If I stick a `print_r($mx_grid)` after the init. loop:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
      [0] => null [1] => 6 ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
      [0] => null [1] => 6 ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
      [0] => null [1] => 6 ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
      [0] => null [1] => 6 ) . . . .
```

Nice, healthy array? Right?

After the `_menu_add_cell()`, same thing, except with the content I set.

After the `_menu_compile()`, same thing.

In the `_menu_compile`, after the global variables are pulled in:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => /api/meh [1] => 0 ) ) )
```

That is it. All it is. The content is correct, but where is the rest of the array?

Comment: "Something something that's why global vars are the devil." ~ Someone Smart. Probably.

Comment: p.s. I ran your code as-is I don't see it outputting a final short-nested array like that.

Comment: @CrayonViolent : I took it out of debug when I posted, but it is back in DEBUG MODE now.

Comment: yeah I got that.. I added some `print_r` calls throughout your script just like you have, even before you edited.. like I said, as-is, I don't see a truncated array. This is what outputs for me. http://pastebin.com/Gh8TdVLY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this produces the output you're looking for ...

```
<?php

$mx_grid = null;
$mx_generated_menu = '';
$mx_menu_colors = array(
    'blue',
    'red',
    'blue',
    'green',
    'purple',
    ''
);

define('MENU_PAGE', 0);
define('MENU_ACTION', 1);
define('MENU_USER', 2);
define('MENU_LOCAL', 3);
define('MENU_ADMIN', 4);

for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++) {
    $mx_grid[$i] = array();
    for ($j = 0; $j < 6; $j++)
        $mx_grid[$i][$j] = array('null', $j);
}

function _menu_add_cell($x, $y, $action, $type) {
    global $mx_grid;
    $arr = array($action, $type);
    $mx_grid[$y][$x] = $arr;
}

function _menu_compile() {
    global $mx_grid;
    global $mx_generated_menu;
    global $mx_menu_colors;
    $mx_menu_rows = 32;
    $mx_menu_cols = 6;

    $s_t = '';
    $s_r = '';
    $s_i = '';
    $s_c = '';
    for ($r = 0; $r < $mx_menu_rows; $r++) {
        $mx_row = $mx_grid[$r];
        $s_r = "\t<div class='mx_grid mx_menu_grid'>\n";
        for ($c = 0; $c < $mx_menu_cols; $c++) {
            $mx_cell = $mx_row[$c];
            $s_c = $mx_menu_colors[$mx_cell[1]];
            $s_i = "\t\t<div class='mx_grid_cell mx_menu_btn {$s_c}'   href='{$mx_cell[0]}'></div>\n";
            $s_r .= $s_i;
        }
        $s_r .= "\t</div>\n";
        $s_t .= $s_r;
    }
    $mx_generated_menu = $s_t;
    echo $mx_generated_menu;
 }

 _menu_add_cell(1, 1, '/api/meh', MENU_PAGE);

 _menu_compile();
```

I used array() instead of [] because I have an older version of PHP

The issues with the original code included an array subscript that was out of range and improper formatting in one of the strings.